# Yii2 assets not found when using nginx as reverse proxy on apache

Tags: apache, nginx, yii2, reverse-proxy

I am testing nginx as reverse proxy on Xampp apache web server on my local machine. When I open the site on the browser it won't find the css, js and images assets files. When I try to directly include 1 css files on the header without using Yii2 Asset bundle. It is still the same it won't find the files.

Here is my conf file

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include     mime.types;
    include     proxy.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level   5;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_min_length   0;
    gzip_types        text/plain text/css image/x-icon application/x-javascript;
    gzip_vary         on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  21pos.witty.localhost;


    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$
    {
        #root   html;
        root   D:/xamp7.1/htdocs/hr-witty/web;
        expires max;
    }
        #set default location
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    #Optional. If you have a subdomain to serves static files so we have not set up a proxy_pass.
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name s0.jpa.gov.my s1.jpa.gov.my; # Alternately: _

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        access_log logs/static.access.log;
        error_log logs/static.error.log;

        index index.html;

        location / {
            expires     max;
            root   D:/xamp7.1/htdocs/;
        }
    }
}
```

My proxy.conf file

```
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_header_buffer_size 64k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_buffer_size   16k;
    proxy_buffers       32   16k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
```

Comment: You can try my configuration:`location ~ .*.(js|css|ico|png|jpg|gif|ttf|woff|woff2) {root /var/www/my-grid/backend/web;}`

Comment: Its the same. Still can't find files

Comment: You can check the nginx log to determine where the files such as css are pointed to.

Comment: Please post the relevant entries in your access log and error log, and where the actual files are located on your machine.

Comment: @Luna It is now fine. I just didn't restart nginx after adding your configuration. Thanks all